# Difference between directory, path, current folder?

Tags: matlab, path, directory

What is the difference between directory, path and current folder in matlab?

How can you locate these paths?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Good question.

A directory (aka folder) is a normal file system directory.
The current (working) directory or folder is the one retrieved by the pwd() function.
Other functions working on the current directory are cd() and dir().

More important than the current folder is the path (aka search path). It is an ordered list of folders.
The current folder is always, implicitly, at the top of the path.

Now if MATLAB needs to load a file from the file system, it is loaded according the path.
That is, if the file is not in pwd(), then MATLAB will descend along the path until it finds the file.

For example fileread(), fopen() or the *.m file loading work that way, only to mention a few.

It is good practice not to rely on the current directory or cd()-ing into different folders. The reason is that

- you and your code can get easily confused what your pwd() is, and more importantly
- compiled, standalone applications simply do not have a meaningful initial current directory, see http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2008/08/11/path-management-in-deployed-applications/

**Edit**

Also handle addpath() with care. You should not use it inside a function if you care to compile it.

Compiled applications *cannot* modify the path. The only path elements are the unpacked CTF archive and the current directory, but now the latter is *at the bottom* of the path, not at the top as for MATLAB sessions.

Answer (score 0):

So the directory is the folder that MATLAB looks for all the components of your code. For example if you have a function that is defined by you then you need to have the related .m file in the MATLAB directory for instance the same folder as your main code is in. If you have many folders each of them have a function that you need them in your code then need the "path" to be added to directories.
You can simply write

> > addpath('c:/matlab/myfiles')

inyour code or tha main window of MATLAB.
to see the list of folders in your directory type

> > dir